# Laravel eloquent difficult relation query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, orm, eloquent

I'm a system for a friend, but stumbled across a little problem.
I've got 3 models (customerCard, customerCardComment and customerCardFollowup).

It's better if you see the image below to understand what I'm trying to achieve. As you see I'm trying to get a result where I get a customerCard model where the sold field is equal to 0 and the customerCard model has no customerCardComment model where the type field is equal to 1,2 or 3, and the customerCard also does not have any customerCardFollowup.

Databases:
customer_cards
customer_card_comments
customer_card_followups

Both comments and followups table are related to the ID field in customer_cards. Both have foreign keys customer_card_id.

Is there a way to do this query? Or am i lost?
Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Please don't post code as image!

Comment: Also, please provide a rough data structure of your models, or JSON output of a normal query where we can see all relations and attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel's `whereHas` accepts a 3rd and 4th parameter. The 3rd parameter is the comparison operator against the `count` of the result set, and the 4th argument is the `number` to compare against. This will solve the first problem:

```
CustomerCard::where(function($query){
    $query->where('sold', 0)
         ->whereHas('customerCardComment', function($query){
             return $query->whereIn('type', [1,2,3]);
         }, '=', 0);
});
```

Next, you can use `->has()` to count the number of records returned from a relation, this will solve your second problem:

```
CustomerCard::where(function($query){
    $query->where('sold', 0)
         ->whereHas('customerCardComment', function($query){
             return $query->whereIn('type', [1,2,3]);
         }, '=',  0)
         ->has('customerCardFollowup', '=', 0);
});
```

The 3rd one is actually a bit more complex and I need to think about how to approach that a bit more. I'll answer now to get you going in the right direction and edit and update the post with the solution to the 3rd problem shortly.

Comment: I see, this fixes alot of problems for me actually now that I know of this. Didn't know I could use whereHas for relation queries. Thank you. :)